# Does ExpressJs serve as a server?

Tags: node.js, express

I am a learner in Node.js.

1. What is the purpose of Express in NodeJs.?
2. Is it used as server for NodeJs applications?
3. If so, is that used to deploy our nodeJs code and how?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3662110/jmargolisvtI understood that it's a framework used with nodejs to make MVC server side. But just want to know from the server point of view.Like if it's utilised as a server? If so, can we use that server to deploy in production and so?
I read many documentations and watched tutorials, but didn't find much regarding this.
Thanks

Comment: Yes ExpressJS is a famous nodejs framework used in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express is a framework for creating web servers in Node.js. You don't *need* a framework to write a node.js server, but a framework like Express makes your programming job much easier.

Whether you use Express or not makes no difference to how you start your node server.

**Simple node.js server without Express:**

```
// index.js
const http = require('http')  
const port = 3000

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {  
  console.log(request.url)
  response.end('Hello Node.js Server!')
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)

server.listen(port, (err) => {  
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

Launch this server by running `node index.js`.

**Simple node.js server with Express**

```
// index.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Since this application has Express as dependency, you must have Express installed. Run `npm i express` to install express.

Again, launch this server with `node index.js`.

You'll notice both of these examples start an HTTP server on port 3000. If the computer's firewall allows connections on port 3000, people can access your node.js server at http://<your_domain>:3000 or http://<your_ip_address>:3000.

If port 3000 is blocked by a firewall, another possibility is to proxy your node.js server with something like nginx. This has the added benefit of using nginx's features for the initial connection, such as TLS.

You can also modify the code above to have the node.js server run on port 80. This won't work if the computer already has port 80 in use, for example, if apache, nginx, etc. are already running. Node.js can also accept TLS (https) connections directly as well.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Node.js Frameworks Comparison] Here you can see the comparison of **nodejs frameworks** used in production level and their performance.

Comment: So what exactly is the process : is it anything similar to that we do nlfor Angular2 deployment? Like building the code then deploying the same on a server like Nginx?

Comment: It&#39;s basically a MVC framework for building NodeJS apps It adds many functionality above core NodeJS http modules manly to ease the development process easy and quick

Comment: So what is the common procedure to build and deploy a NodeJs application?

Comment: @Amal You deploy with as little as `[root@localhost]# node index.js`, where index.js is your node application. There is no "build" step, unless you are transpiling. You can use something like `forever` to have your application restart if it crashes, and there are fancy things you can do with multiple instances. Whether you use Express or not makes no difference. You can handle connections right in node, or let nginx handle the connection and proxy the request to node. This lets nginx handle the TLS stuff (but node can do that too).